# How to delete multiple local branches in Git with keyword?

Tags: git

So I have multiple local branches (i.e. "TEST-001, TEST-002, TEST-003, etc...") I was wondering how to delete all local branches that contain the keyword "TEST".

So here's what I got so far.

```
git branch | grep "TEST" # ->> WORKS

git branch -d | grep "TEST" # ->> FAILS
```

Answer (score 6):

```
git branch | grep "TEST" | xargs git branch -d
```

Comment: do you have `xargs` installed?

Comment: Yup! I just had to modify the keyword search, but it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for branches in `git branch | grep TEST`; 
    do git branch -D $branches; 
    done
```

try this..